# When do $DA$ and $A$ have the same column space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $K\times Q\quad(K > Q)$ matrix with rank $Q$ and let $D$ be a diagonal matrix with entries $d_1>0,\dots,d_K>0$.

I am interested in knowing what conditions $A$ needs to satisfy so that $A$ and $DA$ have the same column space.

### Edit

Since the rows of $DA$ are multiples of the rows of $A$, the row space remains unchanged and therefore the rank, that is, the number of independent rows and independent columns also is unchanged.  This means that we only have to check whether the columns of $A$, $a_1, \dots, a_Q$, are in the column space of $DA$.  That is the case when the linear systems
$$
\begin{align}
DAx_1 &= a_1 \\
DAx_2 &= a_2 \\
&\vdots
\end{align}
$$
have a solution, or, equivalently, when $AX=B$ for some $X$, where $B=D^{-1}A$.  Now, we know that the reduced row echelon form of $[A|B]$ is schematically
$$
\text{rref}([A|B])=
\left[\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
I & C_1  \\
0 & C_2
\end{array}\right]
$$
thus the condition for $AX=B$ to have a solution is $C_2 = 0$.  But is there a straightforward formula to check $C_2=0$ easily? I guess it involves finding the elimination matrix.

Comment: $A$ can not have any left eigenvector with eigenvalue 0 that is in $D$s rowspace nor can $D$ have any right eigenvector with eigenvalue 0 that is in $A$s column space.

Comment: If D is diagonal it should be sufficient that it has no 0 diagonal element since then it's eigenvalues coincide with diagonal values and no eigenvalue can be 0.

Comment: @mathreadler Am I interpreting this correctly - the intersection of the null space of $A^\top$ and the row space of $D$ must be $\{0\}$? The second condition is automatically satisfied because $D$ is diagonal with diagonal values greater than zero.

Comment: Yes that is what I think is the condition and yes the sure non-negative values in diagonal of $D$ should save us from both directions.

Comment: @mathreadler Ok, but this can't be right...  the rowspace of $D$ is $R^K$, and the nullspace of $A^\top$ can't be $\{0\}$, because we know it's a $(K-Q)$-dimensional subspace, and $K>Q$.  According to this no matrix $A$ satisfies the condition, but there are definitely examples of matrices $A$ for which the columns of $A$ and $DA$ span the same space.

Comment: If the dimensions are compatible for the multiplication to be defined then having a diagonal matrix of non-zero values will never reduce the dimensionality of the space. What may be confusing is that the $D$ from left and the $D$ from right will need to be of different square dimensions depending on number of rows and columns of $A$.

Comment: Educate me here. I thought two or more linearly independent vectors defined a subspace and that scaling those vectors did not change the subspace. Since $AD$ merely scales the column vectors of $A$, then $A$ and $AD$ define the same column space. Also, I believe the only restriction on the elements of $D$ are that they be non-zero.

Comment: @TLDavis What you say is correct but the question is about the matrix $DA$, which scales the row vectors, not the column vectors.

Comment: @mathreadler Yes, the dimensionality of the row and column spaces is unchanged, but the question is whether the column space is unchanged. I edited the question to make this more clear. If you still think your answer is correct feel free to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is real or complex, one necessary and sufficient condition for $DA$ and $A$ to have identical column spaces is that $AA^+DA=DA$ and $AA^+D^{-1}A=D^{-1}A$, where $A^+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of $A$.

Since $AA^+$ is the orthogonal projection into the column space of $A$, this condition means that $\operatorname{ran}(DA)\subseteq\operatorname{ran}(A)$ and $\operatorname{ran}(D^{-1}A)\subseteq\operatorname{ran}(A)$. However, as $\operatorname{ran}(D^{-1}A)\subseteq\operatorname{ran}(A)$ if and only if $\operatorname{ran}(A)\subseteq\operatorname{ran}(DA)$, the subset relationships collectively mean exactly that $\operatorname{ran}(DA)=\operatorname{ran}(A)$.

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't $\text{ran}(DA)\subseteq\text{ran}(A)$ imply $\text{ran}(DA)=\text{ran}(A)$, given that both subspaces have the same number of dimensions?

Comment: @ErnestA Yes, you are right. As $D$ is invertible (it doesn't matter whether it's diagonal or not), $DA$ and $A$ have the same rank, so we only need inclusion in one direction to enforce equality.